# create site collection using sharepoint designer 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have a list with fields
Title
Description
Url
site owner
site member

I want that when user add item to it, new site collection should get created under like www.sharepoint-domain.com/sites/...

Can someone help me how to create site collection through sharepoint designer 2013. Thanks

Comment: Please try this & let me know it any query....https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-sharepoint-site-using-sp-designer-workflow/ 



http://www.connectorman.com/create-sites-with-spd-2013-workflow/

Comment: I don't think that there is OOTB way how to create **site collection** using SharePoint Workflow nor 2010 nor 2013. You can create only subsite in existing site collection. You woul'd have to create custom Workflow activity or custom WCF service that will do it.

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done directly.

You can create Site collection only with central admin, or powershell.

You could get a powershell script to look for a field created by designer and use that as a trigger to get powershell to create a site collection, perhaps. You'd have to run the powershell script on a schedule to make it fire regularly.